# Viewing code inserted by the Java compiler

Tags: java, compilation

Can a Java class file be decompiled is such a way as to show all code added by the compiler?  For example, the Java compiler inserts a no argument constructor whenever no explicit constructor is found.  When I decompile a class file with no explicit constructor, however, the one inserted by the compiler doesn't show up.  Another example would be the compiler's insertion of an "extends java.lang.Object" in any class that doesn't explicitly extend some other class.  Again, when I decompile such a class, I'm not seeing the "extends" component of the class declaration in the decompiled text.  Perhaps I'm taking the fact that the Java compiler "inserts" code too literally?  Maybe I need a more sophisticated decompiler?

Comment: Consider reading the byte code instead.

Comment: If I might, I'd ask that any down votes be accompanied by an explanatory comment.  It's not always apparent, even after later review, why a post might be unclear, not useful, or showing no effort at research, which are the criteria for a down vote.  Thanks much.

Comment: How would you think the "shows not effort at research" (which I personally think is the issue here, even if I did not downvote) criteria can be handled?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Better use a byte code viewer as ASMifier from [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/). Some instructions added by the compiler are skipped at decompiling, in order to keep the source code and the decompiled code close.

You will find the default constructor by the signature `public <init>()V`. It is added to the byte code if no constructor was defined.

Comment: Thanks CoronA.  You and Thorbjørn set me on the right path. Using a bytecode viewer I do  see the default no arg constructor as well as a bunch of other code that the decompiler doesn't show.  I don't however see "extends java.lang.Object" in a class declaration that is a direct descendant of Object.  I take this as confirmation of your observation that some code is added at runtime and not by the compiler.

Comment: The "Some defaults... by the runtime" statement is incorrect.

Comment: `extends ArrayList` appears in the byte code, `extends Object` does not. But the constructor could be always found in the byte code. So I corrected my statement.

Comment: The "(e.g. default inheritance by Object) are not written" is incorrect. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1 "If the value of the super_class item is zero, then this class file must represent the class Object, the only class or interface without a direct superclass."

Comment: I do not see incorrectness. Every super class other than object is directly readable from the byte code (its name resides in the constant pool). The class `java.lang.Object` is symbolized by `zero` but you won't find its name in the byte code. Byte code viewers do not display this information. Of course the runtime resolution is trivial (if zero then Object), but this decoding is an interpretation done at runtime.

Comment: No, super_class field is only zero when you are loading the class file for java.lang.Object. All other classes that directly extend Object have a super_class item that points to a CONSTANT_Class_info that has "java/lang/Object". I though the sentence in the JVM spec was pretty clear "if super_class is zero, then *this class* [emphasis added] must represent the class Object"